# How to authenticate kubectl using environment variables?

Tags: kubectl

The only two ways I can find to authenticate is by creating a new authentication context, e.g.

```
kubectl config set-credentials gajus/foo --token=foo
kubectl config set-cluster foo --insecure-skip-tls-verify=true --server=https://127.0.0.1
kubectl config set-context default/foo/gajus --user=gajus/foo --namespace=default --cluster=foo
kubectl config use-context default/foo/gajus
```

and by using the command line options, e.g.

```
kubectl --server=https://127.0.0.1 --insecure-skip-tls-verify=true --token=foo get po
```

Is there a way to set values for `--server` and other authentication options using environment variables?

Answer (score 4):

The configuration file for credentials live under `$HOME/.kube/config` (kubeconfig). You can create multiple configuration files like that and use the `KUBECONFIG` environment variable to point to the file you want to use for the current session.

```
export KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/config-foo
kubectl config set-credentials gajus/foo --token=foo
kubectl config set-cluster foo --insecure-skip-tls-verify=true --server=https://127.0.0.1
kubectl config set-context default/foo/gajus --user=gajus/foo --namespace=default --cluster=foo
kubectl config use-context default/foo/gajus

export KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/config-bar
...

KUBECONFIG=$HOME/.kube/config-foo kubectl get pod
KUBECONFIG=$HOME/.kube/config-bar kubectl get pod
```